# getAccounts in web3 js undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, dapps, react

I am working on dapp with web3js 1.0.0.37-beta with reactjs.
I got blank in web3.eth.getAccounts. Following is my code

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import web3 from './web3.js';
import voting from './voting.js';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
     account: '',

  }
}

componentDidMount = async () =>  {        
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();               
    console.log(accounts[0]);          
}
```

**web3.js**

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
export default web3;
```

**voting.js**

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = "0xd278D619eBca4583bc9923F0ac0043525CD08bA8";

const abi = [.......];

export default web3.eth.contract(abi, address);
```

I got error in console

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute ethereum.enable() first, see: https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/Advanced_Concepts/Provider_API

Alternatively you could disable the privacy mode of metamask (in settings / Security & Privacy) See https://medium.com/metamask/introducing-privacy-mode-42549d4870fa

By the way web3.js 1.2.1 is available now